# Adding a part-of-speech column to a dataframe

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following data frame called df2 I created from a collection of words that includes columns for frequency and a cumulative total:

```
    word      freq    cum_total     
0   nesoi     1970    1970          
1   cotton    734     2704          
2   exceeding 732     3436          
3   fiber     620     4056          
4   part      618     4674
```

I want to add a column to the table above using NLTK that shows the part of speech the each word in the 'word' column belongs to so the output looks something like this:

```
    word      freq    cum_total  part_of_speech   
0   nesoi     1970    1970       noun
1   cotton    734     2704       noun    
2   exceeding 732     3436       adverb      
3   fiber     620     4056       adjective   
4   part      618     4674       pronoun
```

Here is my code:

```
import nltk
df2['part_of_speech']=df2['word'].apply(nltk.pos_tag)
```

the resulting output looks like this:

```
    word      freq    cum_total  part_of_speech   
0   nesoi     1970    1970       [(n, JJ), (e, NN), (s, NN), (o, NN), (i, NN)]  
1   cotton    734     2704       [(c, NNS), (o, VBP), (t, JJ), (t, NN), (o, NN)...    
2   exceeding 732     3436       [(e, NN), (x, NNP), (c, VBZ), (e, JJ), (e, IN)...      
3   fiber     620     4056       [(f, NN), (i, NN), (b, VBP), (e, NN), (r, NN)]   
4   part      618     4674       [(p, NN), (a, DT), (r, NN), (t, NN)]
```

How do I code to get the desired part_of_speech column for based on the 'word' column?  Tag equivalent is OK (2 or 3 character short form for POS).

Answer (score 0):

The `pos_tag` function assumes that the input is a document/text composed of multiple words and separated by spaces. The solution here is to encapsulate the input in a list. In addition, you can pull the pos directly from the nested list/tuple output:

```py
import nltk
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'words':['this','apple','run','pretty']})

df['pos'] = df['words'].apply(lambda x: nltk.pos_tag([x])[0][1])
```

This gives you:

```
    words pos
0    this  DT
1   apple  NN
2     run  VB
3  pretty  RB
```

Comment: beat me to it...was going to say: `df['pos'] = pd.Series(nltk.pos_tag(df['words'])).apply(lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: Yep, that looks good too. isn't it kind of bizarre though that it would be written to not be able to distinguish between an array of words vs. a string?

Comment: Great, being new to Python coding what do [0][1] mean at the end of the expression?

Comment: The response is returned as a list with tuples inside it, so `[(a,b), (c,d)...(x,y)]`. I'm first indexing into the first element of the list with `[0]`, then indexing into the second element of the tuple with `[1]`. This will get you the part of speech in the tuple and nothing else. Did this answer your question?